# Error: Got unexpected extra arguments (workers=4 0.0.0.0)

Tags: python, docker, gunicorn, fastapi, uvicorn

I am trying to run fastapi with docker but i am getting this error `Error: Got unexpected extra arguments (workers=4 0.0.0.0)`. I am running background tasks using `BackgroundTask` in fastapi so i need to add `worker` in CMD. but i am getting error when i do

`Dockerfile`

```py
FROM tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn:python3.8-slim
COPY ./requirements.txt ./requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r ./requirements.txt
COPY ./app ./app
COPY ./inputs ./inputs
COPY ./model ./model
COPY ./tests ./tests
COPY ./gunicorn.config.py ./gunicorn.config.py
COPY ./Procfile ./Procfile
CMD ["uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--host","TIMEOUT=300","workers=4", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "80"]
```

`gunicorn.config.py`

```py
bind = "0.0.0.0:8080"
workers = 4
timeout = 300
# Using Uvicorn's Gunicorn worker class
worker_class = "uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker"
```

Comment: You seem to have inserted random parameters between the `--host` parameter and its value, `0.0.0.0`: `"--host", "0.0.0.0", "--timeout", "300","--workers", "4"` might work better (parameter, value). Check uvicorns parameter reference to see if my parameter names are correct; I don't have access to the documentation right now

Comment: ...or if those settings are in the config file, you don't need to repeat them as command-line arguments.